# How to treat compressed folders as files using ShellObject from WindowsAPICodePack?

Tags: c#, compressed-folder

I am trying to implement a filesystem browser using the WindowsAPICodePack for C# (.Net 4), and it works pretty well, except that the ShellObject system treats zip files as folders, whereas I'd prefer they be files. Is there some way I can force it to work this way? The low-level interop it does is beyond me.

As far as I can tell, internally it asks if the item is a Folder or a Filesystem element. It then uses this (and some type checks) to figure out what it actually is. Is it safe to force it to treat it as a file if it's Compressed? Or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well first, I saw that there was a flag in `ShellNativeMethods.SFGAO` called `SFGAO_COMPRESSED`. This doesn't seem to actually appear ever though, maybe it was deprecated?

Failing that, I eventually just cheated and did the following in ShellObjectFactory.cs:

Below:

```
// Is this item a Folder?
bool isFolder = (sfgao & ShellNativeMethods.SFGAO.SFGAO_FOLDER) != 0;
```

I added:

```
// Is this a compressed Folder?
bool isCompressedFolder = (itemType == ".zip");
```

And then I replaced

```
else if (isFolder)
```

with

```
else if (isFolder && !isCompressedFolder)
```

This is a total hack, but it seems to work, so unless someone has a better idea I'm sticking with this. Hopefully it'll help someone else out in the future, posts on the WindowsAPICodePack seem pretty rare.

Comment: So what happens with .rar's and .7z's?

Comment: Windows can't natively open those like it can with .zip, so it's thankfully not a problem.

Comment: I'm absolutely struggling with the same problem as you, I am testing SFGAO.COMPRESSED as 0x04000000 and somewhere else I read as 0x80, both always return zero :( This is incredible they both don't work, it's a standard Windows API interface, there must be something we are overlooking. :(

Comment: It's been months since I tried this, but as I recall I pulled my hair out for days before giving up and just doing the horrible ".zip" hack shown above (didn't post the question until after I'd been stumped for a while). There's depressingly little documentation on the WindowsAPICodePack. The official documentation on SFGAO says it's 0x04000000 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762589.aspx